# Using MS Graph in daemon apps requires Application type permissions in Azure AD

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, daemon

The [examples from here](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) require Application type permissions, which means, that such app will have access to all mailboxes in the tenant. Which, basically, means that it can't be just any tenant, because under normal circumstances, access to all mailboxes is a no-no.

I.e., it seems to be only practical for the tenants, which are narrowly specialised in handling certain mail, and does not contain any regular individual's mail.

The question: is there, perhaps, any way to run a daemon with only delegated permissions configured for the app? That would seem to solve the predicament.

Comment: From what I know, you can limit a daemon app's permissions in Exchange Online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access. Delegated permissions are also possible, but require user-specific setup, handling refresh tokens, and potentially requiring users to consent to access again. Check if the application access policy could be used in your case first :)

Comment: @juunas, thank you very much! Running  New-ApplicationAccessPolicy command restricted the access to only one mailbox. That's definitely an option, although I would prefer, "everything is denied, by default", rather than, as in this case "everything is allowed, denying is optional".

What about the "user-specific setup, handling refresh tokens, etc. " - can you give more details on this, perhaps?

Comment: I added an answer with some details :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to limit the daemon app's permissions in Exchange Online with an application access policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access.

The other more complicated way is to use delegated permissions through refresh tokens.
The process for that looks like this:

1. User who wants to give the app access to send emails from their mailbox signs in to the app (you need some kind of front-end)
2. The app receives an ID token, an access token, and a refresh token
3. ID token tells the app who the user is, so they can get for example the user's unique immutable id from there (the oid claim) in order to identify the user who gave access
4. The access token isn't really necessary here, so the app can throw that away
5. The refresh token on the other hand is stored in a secret store
6. Daemon app wants to send an email, so it gets the refresh token from secret store
7. A new access token and refresh token are acquired from Azure AD using the refresh token
8. The new refresh token is stored in the secret store to replace the existing one
9. The daemon app uses the access token to send the email as the user

The daemon app needs to be ready for the inevitable situation where the refresh token doesn't work though.
It could have expired for various reasons.
In that situation the first steps need to be repeated for that user.

The refresh token can also expire if not used, though this may have changed in recent times.
In the past we made a process that would ensure that each refresh token got at least used to acquire new tokens once a week to keep them fresh.

So you can see that the daemon app approach with application permissions is a lot simpler and more robust (just have to make sure the secret/certificate doesn't expire).
On the other hand the approach with delegated permissions is fundamentally more secure as you can't gain more access than what the user has.
Individual users can also revoke consent.

Comment: thanks for the details! Are you aware of any working example for the second scenario with azure and/or office 365? We have done similar things with social media, and the details are different with every identity provider (and, of course, the devil is in the detail).

Comment: No, I'm not aware of one sadly :\ I've implemented this in a customer project which I can't share here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to read one particular AD user's mailbox, you may be able to use the Integrated Windows provider, which uses delegated permissions.  While this is meant more for desktop/mobile apps, it can be used in daemon apps as well.  The nice thing about it is it allows you to get a token silently, with no user interaction required.  There are a few caveats, however, which admittedly limits its scope:

- The app must be running as the user whose mailbox you are trying to access.
- The user cannot have MFA enabled (since that requires user interaction--may not be an issue for a service account user).
- You would need to enable the "Allow public client flows" app setting in the Azure portal.

The code would then look something like below.  More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#integrated-windows-authentication) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#integrated-windows-provider).

```
AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");

IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(config.ClientId)
    .WithTenantId(config.Tenant)
    .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{config.ApiUrl}.default" };

var authProvider = new Microsoft.Graph.DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
    var result = await app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

    request.Headers.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
});

var graphClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var messages = await graphClient.Users["TheUser@YourDomain.com"].Messages.Request()
    .Select("sender,subject").GetAsync();  // substitute your user
```